# Setting up RESTful environment in Eclipse Oxygen and Tomcat 9

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I have been following [this](https://www.pegaxchange.com/2016/08/11/jax-rs-java-rest-service-eclipse-tomcat/) tutorial but with the above mentioned specs and Java 9 jdk which came by default with my Macbook. I have manually added Java EE 6 API jar to my class path even to test it is the path I made a Test.java and test by the `import javax.ws.rs.Path;` but I still keep encountering this error when I try to add the jersey jars (JAX-RS) to the project facets. Below is the screenshot. The problem is when it says `Required class java.ws.rs.Path does not exist in selected libraries`. What exactly is going on wrong here? Thanks in advance. This is an attempt to see if not the latest but one of the recent specs can work together in an environment.

[image]

Comment: The tutorial mentions java 8 so that's probably the issue, you are using java 9.

Comment: Are you actually sure it is in the project's Java Build Path? As in, have you looked?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz The error is nothing to do with the version of Java being used. It's related to the addition of jar files to the User Libraries list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those [tutorial](https://www.pegaxchange.com/2016/08/11/jax-rs-java-rest-service-eclipse-tomcat/) instructions worked for me. For the error you are getting I think you must have missed this specific step:
[image: Rest1]

To verify that as the problem, select the list of user libraries using **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries**, then select **JAX-RS_Jersey_API** and expand that entry. It should look similar to this screen shot but I suspect that the first entry is missing for you:

[image: Rest2]

I used the latest version of Jersey (2.26) which is based on JAX-RS 2.1 rather than JAX-RS 2.0 which the tutorial used, so my file name is slightly different form the one in the tutorial, but that discrepancy does not matter. The important thing is that you see an entry for **javax.ws.rs-api-*.jar** in **User Libraries**.

If you don't see the entry then repeat the step in the tutorial pasted above and everything should be fine. However, if you already have that entry please update your post with a screen shot similar to the **User Libraries** one shown above.